# Print to shell Python in curses

Tags: python-curses

I found a question whose title is "Print to standard console in curses". Here describes a solution with an object that replaces the sys.stdout to print to standard console after close the curse screen. I tested this solution and works correctly but I would like to know how could i print something to a python shell?.
the programming code is the following

```
class stdoutwrapper:
  text=""
  def write(self,txt):
    self.text +=txt
    self.text='\n'.join(self.text.split('\n')[-30:])
  def get_text(self,beg,end):
    return '\n'.join(self.text.split('\n')[beg:end])
if __name__=="__main__":
  mystdout=stdoutwrapper()
  sys.stdout=mystdout
  sys.stderr=mystdout
  print "bienvenido"
...........
..........
..........
...........
# Main program
  processmenu(menu_data)
  curses.endwin() #VITAL! This closes out the menu system and returns you to the bash prompt.
  os.system('clear')
  sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__
  sys.stderr=sys.__stderr__
  sys.stdout.write(mystdout.get_text(0,30))
```

After exit from curse screen, the out in standard console is:

bienvenido

c:\users\casalino>

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that I completely understand your question.
If you want to print text in curses program - you should use something like that:

```
screen = curses.initscr()
screen.noecho()

screen.addstr(y=5, x=5, "My_string")
self.screen.refresh()
```

For example [here](https://gist.github.com/pankshok/38befec8fc26ca48da3f) is my curses dummy "screensaver".

Python curses [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html).

If you want to print some debug values then it's better to use logger module and log to file.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh, so old question! I not looked at post date:)